# Can this template function be adapted to account for the following method?

Tags: templates, visual-c++, mfc, safearray

This question is a followon to this one:

- [Can these methods that convert safe arrays into std::list objects be turned into a template function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65570588/2287576)

This is my new template function:

```
template<typename from, typename to>
void CMSATools::ConvertSAFEARRAY(SAFEARRAY* psaItems, to& rItems)
{
    from* pVals = nullptr;
    HRESULT hr = SafeArrayAccessData(psaItems, (void**)&pVals); // direct access to SA memory

    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        long lowerBound, upperBound;  // get array bounds
        hr = SafeArrayGetLBound(psaItems, 1, &lowerBound);
        if (FAILED(hr))
            throw _com_error(hr);

        hr = SafeArrayGetUBound(psaItems, 1, &upperBound);
        if (FAILED(hr))
            throw _com_error(hr);

        rItems.clear();
        long cnt_elements = upperBound - lowerBound + 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < cnt_elements; ++i)  // iterate through returned values
        {
            rItems.push_back(pVals[i]);
        }
        hr = SafeArrayUnaccessData(psaItems);
        if (FAILED(hr))
            throw _com_error(hr);
    }
    else
    {
        throw _com_error(hr);
    }

    hr = SafeArrayDestroy(psaItems);
    if (FAILED(hr))
        throw _com_error(hr);
}
```

I have this other method that I would like to be able to use with the template function above:

```
void CMSATools::ConvertSAFEARRAY_BSTR(SAFEARRAY* psaStrings, CStringArray& rAryStrings)
{
    BSTR *pVals = nullptr;
    HRESULT hr = SafeArrayAccessData(psaStrings, (void**)&pVals); // direct access to SA memory

    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        long lowerBound, upperBound;  // get array bounds
        hr = SafeArrayGetLBound(psaStrings, 1, &lowerBound);
        if (FAILED(hr))
            throw _com_error(hr);

        hr = SafeArrayGetUBound(psaStrings, 1, &upperBound);
        if(FAILED(hr))
            throw _com_error(hr);

        rAryStrings.RemoveAll();
        long cnt_elements = upperBound - lowerBound + 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < cnt_elements; ++i)  // iterate through returned values
        {
            CString strPublisher(pVals[i]);

            rAryStrings.Add(strPublisher);
        }
        hr = SafeArrayUnaccessData(psaStrings);
        if (FAILED(hr))
            throw _com_error(hr);
    }
    else
    {
        throw _com_error(hr);
    }

    hr = SafeArrayDestroy(psaStrings);
    if (FAILED(hr))
        throw _com_error(hr);
}
```

- `from` is easy: `BSTR`.
- `to` is easy: `CStringArray`.

The problem is that all of the other parameters were derived from `std::list` and we used `push_back`. In this instance, when it is of type `CStringArray` I need to use `Add(...)` (and also create the `CString` element first).

I see lots of suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13636540/how-to-check-for-the-type-of-a-template-parameter) but it is not clear to me what the simplest approach should be.

---

It seems I should be able to is: `std::is_same<from,CStringArray>::value` to see if they are the same, but the answers seem to frown on using this approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Complications in this case are the `clear` and `push_back` calls which `CStringArray` does not implement. While both can be solved generically as described in [Templated check for the existence of a class member function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257288/templated-check-for-the-existence-of-a-class-member-function) for example, a simpler approach can work to cover just the proposed case by using a couple of helper function templates.

```
// default implementations for <T, std::list<T>>
template<typename to>
void to_clear(to &rItems)
{   rItems.clear(); }

template<typename from, typename to>
void to_push_back(const from &rItem, to &rItems)
{   rItems.push_back(rItem); }

// specializations for <BSTR, CStringArray>
template<>
void to_clear(CStringArray &rItems)
{   rItems.RemoveAll(); }

template<>
void to_push_back(const BSTR &rItem, CStringArray &rItems)
{   rItems.Add(rItem); } // implicit CString conversion

// e.g.  ConvertSAFEARRAY<int, std::list<int>>
//       ConvertSAFEARRAY<IDiscussionItemPtr, ListDiscussionItems>
//       ConvertSAFEARRAY<BSTR, CStringArray>
template<typename from, typename to>
void ConvertSAFEARRAY(SAFEARRAY* psaItems, to& rItems)
{
    from* pVals = nullptr;
    HRESULT hr = SafeArrayAccessData(psaItems, (void**)&pVals); // direct access to SA memory

    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        long lowerBound, upperBound;  // get array bounds
        hr = SafeArrayGetLBound(psaItems, 1, &lowerBound);
        if (FAILED(hr))
            throw _com_error(hr);

        hr = SafeArrayGetUBound(psaItems, 1, &upperBound);
        if (FAILED(hr))
            throw _com_error(hr);

        to_clear<to>(rItems);
        long cnt_elements = upperBound - lowerBound + 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < cnt_elements; ++i)  // iterate through returned values
        {
            to_push_back<from, to>(pVals[i], rItems);
        }
        hr = SafeArrayUnaccessData(psaItems);
        if (FAILED(hr))
            throw _com_error(hr);
    }
    else
    {
        throw _com_error(hr);
    }

    hr = SafeArrayDestroy(psaItems);
    if (FAILED(hr))
        throw _com_error(hr);
}
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your sample code with explanations which I have now sucessfully managed to interface into my class. I updated all instances of my method with the new one and it is working well. :) This means that I have one more safe array conversion function to try and adapt. I will try using the suggestions in this answer and if I get stuff I will ask a new question.

Comment: I have encountered problems trying to compile the final function using similar approach. I put the question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65592912/i-tried-to-add-a-new-template-helper-function-to-my-class-and-now-i-get-a-lnk200